# Create user profile with user choice on firestore using redirect

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux-firebase

I am creating a site using [react-redux-firebase](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase), and when a user logs in with facebook I want to create a profile that stores a user choice. I know how to define what to store with the profileFactory, but I don't know how to pass dynamic data coming from the user. In my case I want to save the users' language. My configuration is similar to this:

```
const config = {
  userProfile: 'users', // where profiles are stored in database
  profileFactory: (userData, profileData) => { // how profiles are stored in database
    const { user } = userData
    return {
      language: [i need to put here what the user chose]
      email: user.email
    }
  }
}
```

The configuration was based on this [recipe](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/blob/94580288a028d14bc474a336a756138c0d072eb9/docs/recipes/profile.md#change-how-profiles-are-stored).

When logging in I'm using type redirect.

```
 await firebase.login({
        provider: 'facebook',
        type: 'redirect'
      })
```

How could I save the user choice when the user is created?

Answer (score 1):

To solve the user custom fields I'm creating a user when the redirect comes back from facebook.

I'm still not totally sure this is the best way to do it. Seems odd that I can define a profileFactory but can't pass user custom fields in some way.